# Using Eloquent Relationships to retrieve a model through relationships and specific parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have been struggling trying to get the following query converted to Eloquent:

```
SELECT * FROM induction_modules INNER JOIN inductions ON induction_modules.induction_id = inductions.id INNER JOIN induction_user ON induction_user.induction_id = inductions.id WHERE induction_user.user_id = 1 AND induction_modules.id = 56;
```

The relationships are defined as follows:

- User belongsToMany Induction
- Induction belongsToMany User
- InductionModule belongsTo Induction (and reversed with hasOne)
- InductionModuleItem belongsTo InductionModule (and reversed with hasOne).

Now my function is as follows:

```
/**
* Find specific induction module of user
*
* @param int $id
* @param int $inductionModuleID
* @param array $with
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function inductionModule($id, $inductionModuleID, $with = array())
{
    $user = $this->find($id);

    if ($user)
    {
          return /* HOW DO I GET THE MODULE WITH ITS ITEMS?? */
    }

    return null;
}
```

Ideally, what I want to do:

```
$inductionModule = $user->inductions()->modules()->with('items)->WHEREMODULEID=56.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, but I've not tested it.

```
$user = User::with(array('inductions.modules.items' => function($q)
{
    $q->where('induction_modules.id', 56);      
}))->find(1);

foreach($user->inductions as $induction) {
    // echo $induction->description;
    foreach($induction->modules as $module) {
        // echo $module->description;
        foreach($module->items as $item) {
            // echo $item->description;
        }
    }
}
```